# How to scale Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have following highstocks:

[image]

I want to have proper scale on this chart so few month would be much longer than few days. How can I achieve this?

This chart is `area` type with `step: true` and `stacking: 'normal'`

Comment: I do not believe HighStock can do non-linear xAxis.

Comment: So am I forced to fill my data with intermediate values?

Comment: "Non-linear xAxis" was key. Thanks. I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438937/highstock-highcharts-irregular-data-gets-wrong-x-scale and this is what I wanted.