# highcharts is not respecting my x-axis' date interval

Tags: highcharts

I have a series of data collected every 15 minutes for a few weeks. Unfortunately, there's a week of missing data in the middle. This is just a fact of my business.  When I use Highcharts to chart this data, it compresses the x-axis (time), skewing the chart. For example, the x-axis has major ticks every 2 hours until the missing week.  Then it jumps to major ticks of *days*.

Regardless of the data, I need the x-axis to remain consistent. If this causes a large gap in the diagram, so be it.

I have skimmed the documentation but found nothing. If anyone could direct me to the relevant page that would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13439281/1566575

You will need to set the **[`xAxis.ordinal`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal)** property to `false`, this is `true` by default. `True` value indicates the points should be placed at fixed intervals w.r.t **space (pixels)**, and `False` changes points to be placed at fixed intervals w.r.t. **time**

```
xAxis: {       
    ordinal: false
}
```

**[Linear x-axis | Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/ytcW3/)**

Docs:
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal