# Highstockcharts - distance between datetime values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

In one of my projects, I'm using the highstock chart: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo
The problem I have is rather visual than functional :)
Spacing between the values on x-axis is the same but it should reflect the actual dates.
For example, the spacing between the 1st and 2nd bar (15. Feb and 5.May) is the same as the spacing between the 4th and 5th bar (19. May and 20. May).

```
5. May - 15. Feb = 79 days  
20. May - 19. May = 1 day
```

So I'd like to have 79x bigger space between 1st and 2nd bar than 4th and 5th.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you set `xAxis.ordinal = false` ? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557734/highcharts-is-not-respecting-my-x-axis-date-interval).

Comment: `xAxis.ordinal = false` solved the problem! thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highstock highcharts irregular data gets wrong x-scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438937/highstock-highcharts-irregular-data-gets-wrong-x-scale)